# PDF Reader in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-reader

I want to read PDF files from my .net application. Are there any free libraries available to do this?

Comment: do you want to just read them (to process the text) or actually display them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for free PDF Read/Write .Net library, then you can visit
https://itextpdf.com/ (previously itextsharp)

Note: As mentioned by Dexters, this is library no more free for commercial purpose. It comes under [Affero General Public License (AGPL)](http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/agpl.php)

Comment: Caution: itextsharp i think is not free if yous application is related to any sort of commercial activity.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at PDFSharp: http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/

Answer (score 1):

[PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) is open source and supports [advanced text extraction](http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/textextraction.html). It also supports lucene search so it's ideal for creating a lucene index.

Comment: I guess it requires java runtime.

Comment: From that link: "Even though PDFBox is written in Java, there is also a .NET version that is available."