# Native C# pdf reader

Tags: c#, pdf

I need to extract text from PDF file. I've found iTextSharp and PDFBox, but both of them are only Java ports and to make them work i need to use big additional dlls.

So, my question is: is there some native C# library for extracting text from PDF files? If there is no any, is it hard to write one?

Comment: "If there is no any, is it hard to write it?" If it wasn't hard, someone would've written one already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF Reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905683/pdf-reader)

Comment: No, nothing native, and yes, it's very difficult.

Comment: If iTextSharp does not fill your needs, then you will probably need to go with a commercial (paid) product. And yes, iTextSharp is a port from Java, but it was rewritten in c#, thus managed code.

Comment: @Jim iTextSharp/iText are also paid products unless used in open source projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) may be used to [extract text from PDF](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract) files.

The library has no external dependencies and is written in C#. There are [different license types](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/licenses/) for Docotic.Pdf.

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle.

Comment: Wow, you sure you guys are charging enough for that? Perhaps you could ask for a non-preferential limb as well...

Comment: Well yeah, there was a free version, but now it's $595+. Too expensive!

Answer (score 3):

There's [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.net/)

Comment: PdfSharp doesn't support text **extraction**!