# pdf filled template form convert into Excel or CSV?

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, livecycle

We have bunch of PDF forms filled by users (this template made in Adobe LiveCycle Designer). User entered data in PDF files. Now I have convert into CSV or Excel file.

How to do that? Any tools available? Any .net code can do that?

Comment: can't say I know much about reading from PDF files, but someone asked a similar question you can probably bum and answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690109/native-c-sharp-pdf-reader

Comment: The AIF forms I deal with have the content filled in by their users stored in an XML structure. During form import we use the ADS (Adobe Document Service) to extract the XML from the PDF and parse it for the needed information.

If you use a similar approach you may want to look out for an XML to Excel converter.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pdftoexcelonline.com/ <-- Here is a tool, but to answer your question, here is another similar post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704287/converting-pdf-to-excel