# Can .Net be used to deal with PDF files natively?

Tags: .net, pdf

Does `.Net` have any facilities to work with `PDF` files natively (such as return a page count) or must an external library be used?

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690109/native-c-sharp-pdf-reader) useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built-in support for working with PDFs.

Comment: I had the wise idea of search the object browser and found Windows.Data.PDF (and other iterations)...sounds compelling. WTH is it?

Comment: Windows.Data.Pdf is a Windows API, a platform-specific helper that is not part of the .NET framework. If you are targeting Windows 8.1 *only*, it would allow you to get a PageCount out of a pdf.